# After installing Lubuntu, data at BTRFS /home partion becomes invisible

Tags: lubuntu, filesystem, btrfs

Today I dusted of my little workforce laptop and replaced the EOL Manjaro with a Lubuntu 17.10 install. I was smart enough to put /home at a separate partition to make distro switching easier. During install I told the installer to use the partition as /home mountpoint and NOT format it.

So far so good. But I discovered that the installer didn't pick my existent home profile folder. Somehow my data at separate /home partition has become invisible despite -a-blackbox-package-about-filesystems- reports that the partition is used for about the same amount as it was before the installation. So for me it seems the data is somewhere.

My underbelly tells me BTRFS is the curpit. But after doing `btrfs subvolume list /home`, only one entry returned. Which placed me on doubt.

Anyone having an idea to get access to the data again?

Sidenote: 
In contrast of the person [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618071/re-install-and-keep-home-partition-with-btrfs-lost-files) my /home partition is correctly mounted and put in fstab (at least it seems). The UUID of that partion in fstab is the same as shown in gparted.

Comment: I don't know much about btrfs tools but the lubuntu desktop does not install btrfs-tools by default so I am not sure if installing that will help.  not sure if it does this when reusing a partition to not install it.

Comment: @ianorlin Well, unfortunately installing btrfs-tools did not resolve it. Still weird btrfs-tools isn't installed when machine has a BTRFS partition present.